# php - switch with opentags in html

Tags: php, html, syntax

I have the following code in a view for setting the selected option for a dropdown
I have used loops for this kind of thing before, but never a switch,
it is breaking at some point for the syntax. is this even possible in php? sorry if it is a dumb mistake.

```
    <?switch($_GET['rows']):?>

      <select name="rows"  onchange="$('#paginacao').submit()">

        <option value="10" <?case 10: echo 'selected'; break;?>>10</option>

        <option value="15" <?case 15: echo 'selected'; break;?>>15</option>
        <option value="20" <?case 29: echo 'selected'; break;?>>20</option>
        <option value="100" <?case 100: echo 'selected'; break;?>>100</option>
      </select>

    <?endswitch;?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is confusing that it should work differently for a specific control structure, the switch-case [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) has a specific requirement about output between the start of the switch statement and the first case: There should be none.

Which means that, in your example, that every single character (apart from the line break) between `<?switch($_GET['rows']):?>` and `<?case 10: echo 'selected'; break;?>` is causing the syntax error.

However, you can simplify your code by simply using ternary conditions:

```
<select name="rows" onchange="$('#paginacao').submit()">
    <option value="10" <?php echo ($_GET['rows'] === 10 ? "selected" : ""); ?>>10</option>
    <option value="15" <?php echo ($_GET['rows'] === 15 ? "selected" : ""); ?>>15option>
    <option value="20" <?php echo ($_GET['rows'] === 20 ? "selected" : ""); ?>>20</option>
    <option value="100" <?php echo ($_GET['rows'] === 100 ? "selected" : ""); ?>>100</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you are right, the documentation makes it very clear.
in the end i used the ternary, the same way you pointed,
but the switch if implemented would be really nice... duno why this limitation

Comment: Switch statement are good to have a different result based on a value (e.g. if you wanted to show an different input for each amount of rows). But for toggling the selected status, using conditions (or ternary, if you fancy using it) is (imho) the best way to do it as it limits code repetition. 
If you wanted to use a switch for this, each case would need to have all the options with only one having the `selected` attribute per case.